# Como justificar o texto inteiro do meu bookdown?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Eu gostaria de justificar o texto do meu bookdown. Este é o código do index.Rmd

```
--- 
title: "A minimal book example"
author: "Alex"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %b de %Y')`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
biblio-style: apalike
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
# url: your book url like https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown
# cover-image: path to the social sharing image like images/cover.jpg
description: |
  This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book.
  The HTML output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook,
  set in the _output.yml file.
link-citations: yes
geometry: "left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo

---
```

[image: Resultado:]

Eu fiz o que sugireram em outro post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616917/how-to-justify-whole-text-in-rmd-with-bookdowngitbook-as-output), mas não deu certo

Muito obrigado!

Comment: No `output.yml` coloque a referência ao CSS `>bookdown::html_book: >  css: style.css` como nos outros formatos, e no CSS coloque `body {text-align: justify;}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it´s ok. But the style changes a little. Do you know if there are more types of styles or themes of outputs?